# how to append a dataframe without overwriting existing dataframe using for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have an empty dataframe[] and want to append additional dataframes using for loop without overwriting existing dataframes, regular append method is overwriting the existing dataframe and showing only the last appended dataframe in output.

Comment: `append` won't overwrite the existing dataframe, unless you want it. `df.append(df1)` won't change `df`. But `df = df.append(df1)` will do.

Comment: i tried 1st option i.e. df.append(df1) within for loop but the output is empty data frame.

Comment: I try to make an answer. Hope you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

use `concat()` from the `pandas` module.

```
import pandas as pd
df_new = pd.concat([df_empty, df_additional])
```

read more about it in the [pandas Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

regarding the question in the comment...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(insert columns which your to-be-appended-df has too)

for i in range(10):
    function_to_get_df_new()
    df = pd.concat([df, df_new])
```

Comment: i want to use append through for loop

Comment: this option "df = pd.concat([df, df_new])" is overwriting the existing frames and giving only last df in output

Answer (score 1):

You can't also use `set`:

```
df_new = pd.concat({df_empty, df_additional})
```

Because `pandas.DataFrame` objects can't be hashed, `set` needs hashed so that's why

Or `tuple`:

```
df_new = pd.concat((df_empty, df_additional))
```

They are little quicker...

Update for `for` loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(your number):
    df_new=function_to_get_df_new()
    df = pd.concat({df, df_new}) # or tuple: df = pd.concat((df, df_new))
```

Comment: i want to add additional dfs through Loop

Comment: @user10234885 Done!

Comment: while doing with 1st (using for loop\  df=pd.concat({df,df_new})) option it is giving me following error:    TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: @user10234885don't use `tuple` or `list` for this `set` is not right sorry fr this

Answer (score 1):

Let you have list of dataframes `list_of_df = [df1, df2, df3]`.

You have empty dataframe `df = pd.Dataframe()`

If you want to append all dataframes in list into that empty dataframe `df`:

```
for i in list_of_df:
    df = df.append(i)
```

Above loop will not change `df1, df2, df3`. But `df` will change.
Note that doing `df.append(df1)` will not change `df`, unless you assign it back to `df` so that `df = df.append(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

The question is already well answered, my 5cts are the suggestion to use `ignore_index=True` option to get a continuous new index, not duplicate the older ones.

```
import pandas as pd

df_to_append = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB')) # sample
df = pd.DataFrame() # this is a placeholder for the destination

for i in range(3):
    df = df.append(df_to_append, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use for loop here, try `concat()`

```
import pandas
result = pandas.concat([emptydf,additionaldf])
```

[pandas.concat documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: In for loop i am calling a function which is generating new dfs , those dfs i want to append in existing empty df